# Ubuntu VM is extremely slow and freezes every third boot

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, hard-drive, ssd, performance

I have been experiencing an extremely peculiar behaviour with my VMs running on Virtual Box. The host is Windows 7 (fresh install). I have a fresh VB install and fresh Ubuntu image 18.04. The settings are as follows:

- 4 CPU cores, PAE/NX enabled (I am running Intel Xeon E5 2640 v4 with 10 cores on the host)
- 4 GB of ram (out of 32 GB on host)
- VT-x + Nested Paging enabled
- 50 GB fixed storage allocation, using SATA controller, HOST I/O cache enabled, "solid state drive" ticked (I have two 500 GB Samsung 850 Evo SSD's in AHCI mode on the host)

The problem is that it barely works. Every third time I try to boot it, it freezes on the "Ubuntu" loading screen, forcing me to power off the machine. When it boots, it's **extremely** slow. It's slow in a sense that when I type in a wrong command in the terminal, it takes ~30 seconds for the system to recognize the command as wrong and say `command not found`.

Using `apt-get install` fetches the files very quickly, but the unpacking part takes ages, maybe ~1 minute per a file to unpack, totaling in 20 minutes to install php5, which is a 25mb package.

The GUI is very responsive. It seems like it's just any drive I/O operation is being slow. However, my I/O speed and usage tests say otherwise - I/O usage is at 0-1% in System Monitor. Running `sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda` gives "Timing cached reads" 9363 MB/sec, "Timing buffered disk reads" 1192 MB/sec.

I have tried reinstalling VB, reinstalling the host OS, creating a new image from scratch, importing an image. My friend has an **identical** hardware and software setup, he doesn't have this issue. It only started happening recently and I honestly have no idea about what's going on, I am out of ideas.

Any advice or suggestion is more than welcome!

Comment: You can disable PAE/NX  and check.

Comment: @sourav, I am installing a new image right now, it's been 4 hours so far and it's still installing, I will do it after this. May I ask you why you think PAE/NX has an effect on it? My friend has the same CPU and is using the same image without any issues.

Comment: @sourav, no difference :(

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was causing the problem or solve it?

Comment: @Zanna as far as I remember I had incorrect settings for the Storage drives. Try unticking "solid state drive" if you have it ticked. Try leaving settings for Motherboard submenu default (only change memory and core number if needed).

Comment: Thanks! That seems pretty useful. You could post it as an answer if you feel like it :)

Comment: I had the same problem when I installed Mac OS on VM. The issue was with low amount of VRAM passed to the virtual machine.

Comment: @Zanna as I am uncertain about the exact solution I would rather leave it in the comments, good luck to you!